# Cosa significa "titolo iridato" riferito agli scacchi?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

In [questo articolo di Euronews](https://it.euronews.com/2018/11/28/scacchi-magnus-carlsen-batte-fabiano-caruana-e-conserva-il-titolo) riferito agli scacchi ho letto:

> Ci sono volute quasi 3 settimane di incontri tra i due fuoriclasse della scacchiera per decretare il vincitore del **titolo iridato**. Dopo le 12 partite a tempo normale finite in parità sono stati decisivi gli spareggi sprint, giocati cioè entro un tempo limitato.

Non capisco il significato di "titolo iridato" nel contesto del brano: potreste spiegarmelo? Ho cercato l'aggettivo "iridato" in alcuni dizionari, ma le definizioni relative all'ambito dello sport che ho trovato fanno riferimento al ciclismo.

Comment: “giocati cioè entro un tempo limitato”: in realtà tutte le partite di questo e qualsiasi altro torneo di scacchi si giocano entro un tempo limitato. Qui il tempo era solo molto ridotto rispetto alle prime 12 partite.

Comment: Hai completamente ragione, @DaG, ma non sono io l'autrice dell'articolo.

Comment: Sì, @Charo, non lo contestavo a te, volevo solo precisare questo aspetto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Da [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maglia_iridata)

> La **maglia iridata** è la maglia distintiva indossata dal campione del mondo in carica di una disciplina del ciclismo. Si tratta di una maglia bianca con cinque bande orizzontali colorate intorno al torace. Dall'alto in basso si hanno bande di colore blu, rosso, nero, giallo e verde, ovvero gli stessi della bandiera olimpica, a simboleggiare i cinque continenti.

*Maglia iridata* è un'espressione comune nel ciclismo (dove sono frequenti anche *maglia gialla* e *maglia rosa* per il vincitore del Giro d'Italia e del Tour de France) che in questo caso è stata riadattata ad un contesto diverso.

Infatti è diventato comune utilizzare il termine *iridato* come sinonimo di "mondiale" nell'ambito delle competizioni sportive (anche se letteralmente non avrebbe senso, dato che la maglia iridata è presente solo nel ciclismo). È possibile che quest'uso sia stato influenzato anche dal fatto che i colori della maglia iridata siano esattamente gli stessi della bandiera olimpica, associata ad un'altra famosa gara internazionale.

In breve, il *titolo iridato* in questo contesto è semplicemente il titolo di campione del mondo di scacchi.

Comment: L'espressione si usa anche per la formula 1 o sbaglio?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Ho il sospetto che sia passato nell'uso comune per indicare un qualsiasi titolo mondiale, anche se non seguo a sufficienza lo sport per confermarlo. Chiaramente il significato letterale non ha senso fuori dal ciclismo :).

Comment: sono d'accordo, è un'espressione che si usa comunemente nell'ambito sportivo.